# Linking to Pages with Flash in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, flash, codeigniter

I've made a website using Flash in CodeIgniter. Normally when you link to a page in CodeIgniter, you use the `anchor()` method, which you pass URL segments to. How am I able to set links to pages within Flash? Hopefully there's a way other than changing the links after the site is installed, and configured. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to have your framework publish some data structure full of links, and have your flash movie grab that structure.  Think some json-encoded hash of some sort.  Of course, you'd probably want your flash movie to stick the data in some client-side store (cookie, or whatever else flash might offer) -- otherwise, you'll creating an extra back-end HTTP call every time the movie loads.

Comment: You should be able to encode it into the original html page as a parameter to the movie. Other than that, a good suggestion.

Comment: Matt, I'd select yours if you submitted it as an answer. :)

Comment: Depending on what you actually do, it's not so much a different answer as another WTDI. I'm not proficient in flash, certainly not enough to write up an answer to the quality I usually attempt to reach (ie, a sample would be nice), I only have a passing knowledge of what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Scharley answered it in the comments. I ended up taking his suggestion of passing everything as URL parameters in the HTML.